# Lodash isEqual fails because of constructor defined by angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constructor, lodash

I am using Lodash _.isEqual to deep-compare a local javascript object with another javascript object retrieved through angular $get.

This code says that the objects are different:

```
$get({...}, function (data) {

  cleanupAngularProps(data);

  if (_.isEqual(data, {name: 'Someone'}) {
    ...
  }
});
```

but chaging it a little as follows it now says that they are equal (as expected):

```
$get({...}, function (data) {

  cleanupAngularProps(data);

  if (_.isEqual(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), {name: 'Someone'}) {
    ...
  }
});
```

I debugged into the Lodash code and it seems to fail because both objects have different constructors.

How can I solve this without cloning the data?

Comment: JSON.parse is also going to get rid of functions...

Comment: It's possible that original `data` contains functions, but when you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)` you create the same object, but without functions. Because of that in the first case `isEqual` return false, in the second true.

Comment: What does `cleanupAngularProps` do? You should be able to get a POJO and the raw JSON from an angularjs $http request which would simplify the comparison with another POJO.

Comment: @ExplosionPills It comes with $promise and $resolved.

Comment: @AlexanderMac I checked and It has no "own" functions. Also deleted all the functions defined within __proto__ but they are still different. This is the condition that fails: [https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/lodash/0.7.0/symbols/_.isEqual#line=1554](https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/lodash/0.7.0/symbols/_.isEqual#line=1554)

Comment: @elclanrs That is my first intention, but let me know if you see any danger on removing them. Maybe I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question is three years old at this point, but I have found what I believe is a more acceptable answer. Simply exclude the prototype comparison between the two objects:

```js
var result = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(data, ['__proto__']),
  _.omit({name: 'Someone'}, ['__proto__'])
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a good practice but I solved it by resetting the prototype, hence the constructor.

```
$get({...}, function (data) {

  cleanupAngularProps(data);

  data.__proto__ = Object.prototype;

  if (_.isEqual(data, {name: 'Someone'}) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need deep comparison and ignore constructors, then you can use this code:

```
const customizer = (a: any, b: any, key: any) => {
            if (_.isObject(a) && _.isObject(b)) {
                // @ts-ignore
                const aProto = a.__proto__.constructor.name
                // @ts-ignore
                const bProto = b.__proto__.constructor.name
                if (aProto != bProto) {
                    return _.isEqualWith(_.omit(a, ['__proto__']), _.omit(b, ['__proto__']), customizer)
                }
            }
            return undefined
        }
_.isEqualWith({foo:1}, {foo:1}, customizer)
```